# How to fix post method error using ExpressJs and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post, postman

I'm new in Express.js,MongoDb and mongoose, I have created HTTP request methods, but when running the Post method, nothing is done (nothing saved in the database), and postman still loading and it stops only when I cancel. I want to know what's wrong in my code, thank you .

```
    router.post("/v1/department", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const request = req.body
        const department = new Department(request)
        await department.save()
        res.status(200).send(department)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
});
```

This is my model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require('validator')


const Department = mongoose.model('Department', {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
    ,
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,//
        lowercase: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Invalid email!')
            }
        }
    }
    ,
    createdBy: {
        type: String,
        default: 'SYS_ADMIN'
    }
    ,
    updatedBy: {
        type: String,
        default: 'SYS_ADMIN'
    }
    ,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
        // ,
        // default: Date.getDate()
    }
    ,
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date
        // ,
        // default: Date.getDate()
    },
    isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
})

module.exports = Department
```

This is the Index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const departmentRouter = require("../src/routes/department")

app.use(express.json())
app.use(departmentRouter)

//app.use('/', require('./routes/department'))

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;//local machine port 3000
app.listen(port, () => (`Server running on local machine port ${port} `));
```

The connection to the database is :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Connect to the local mongoDB database for testing the API localy
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/openemp-api-department', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few things here. Mongoose is never set up in the index.js so there is no connection to the database. [This should help you follow step by step](https://rahmanfadhil.com/express-rest-api/)

Also in your router you're sending department1 which is never assigned.

If the link doesn't work or you need more information let me know.

Comment: The connection to the database is established, just I don't shared the code,

Comment: Please check that route which you try to call is correct. Try to debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of **Express** which is **(Express v4.16.0 and higher)**
Use this in your server.js file: ----->

```
const express = require('express');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

// For Express version less than 4.16.0
// ------------------------------------

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

**otherwise your post request will give you error(like not recognizing any names etc)**
**so make sure to use these according to to express version**
[image]
[image]

**index.js file**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require("axios");

mongoose.connect(
  "YourMongoUri",
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
);
const dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});
const modelData = mongoose.model("modelData", dataSchema);
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  modelData.find((err, doc) => {
    if (err) console.log(err.message);
    else {
      res.send(doc);
    }
  });
});
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const user = new modelData({
    name: req.body.name,
    age: req.body.age,
  });
  user.save((err, doc) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.send(doc);
  });
});
router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const user = modelData.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      name: req.body.name,
      age: req.body.age,
    },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      res.send(doc);
    }
  );
});
router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  modelData.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.send(doc);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js file**

```
const express = require("express");
const myRouter = require("./index");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
s;

app.use("/myroute", myRouter);
app.listen(port, console.log("listening on port 3000"));
```